# Can not delete a local branch after rebase

Tags: git

I have a strange case:

1. I created a copy of an existing branch with the name "test"
2. I did some rebasing on it (only reordered some commits in interactive mode)
3. There was only one conflict, which I solved
4. And I completed rebase
5. Now I want to delete that test branch and I get the following error:

   "error: Cannot delete branch 'test' checked out at 'C:/...FILEPATH..."

I tried those:

1. git branch -d test
2. git branch -D test
3. git branch -d -f test

Comment: You can't delete the current `HEAD` branch. Checkout a different branch, and then try deleting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot delete the branch you're currently using (as indicated by "Cannot delete branch 'test' checked out at"). Check out a different branch first, then try deleting `test`.